# Bundle for test class returns main bundle in Xcode 10, and not unit tests bundle

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, xcode10

We have UnitTests that are hosted in application. To load test resources we use:
`Bundle(for: TestClass.self).path(forResource: "some-file", ofType: "json")`.

In Xcode 9 it returned something like this: `/var/folders/4k/dzpnw8352jn_fl5hcc76pjs8k9qytq/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-707F04EA-2C21-4BA4-8730-00B0EC0F708F/UnitTests-2C97055A-9154-4521-9D12-7CF32FC38793/Session-UnitTests-2018-06-08_141829-RGxhj2.log`

But in Xcode 10 Bundle(for: TestClass.self) returns application bundle path `/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/118AACB9-486C-4E3B-94EA-257C3F082AE1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4234B280-E49C-4044-BAF4-CBFFEA8AFDB4/App.app`

As these files are included to unit test target, they can not be found any more

Update:

**Fixed in Xcode 10.1**

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug in Xcode 10/Swift 4.2 as there is another bug related to `Bundle` in the release notes. You should definitely file a radar to make sure the issue is known.

From Xcode 10 beta release notes

> • The Foundation API Bundle.init(for: AnyClass) always returns the application bundle when used on a class that inherits from a generic class, even if that class itself is not generic. (40367300)

As a potential work around, you could consider using the testing target's bundle identifier.

To find the bundle identifier of the test target, look here:
[image]

#### Update

It seems like `Bundle` has been an ongoing problem with Xcode 10 (really it's Swift 4.2 that's having issues).

From Xcode 10.1 beta 2 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_beta_2_release_notes)

> • The Bundle class's init(for:) initializer now works consistently with Swift classes, including when not running on the latest operating system versions. (44489216)

Comment: Thank you. Let me check looks like exactly issue that I faced

Comment: Can you provide the source to the issue you mentioned above that Bundle.init(for: AnyClass) always returns the application bundle

Comment: @dev296 It was in the Xcode 10 beta release notes which are sadly not accessible anymore. I've updated my answer with a reference to a similar issue fixed in Xcode 10.1 beta

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed in Xcode 10.1 as mentioned in the release notes Resolved Issues
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes

Answer (score 0):

After some class refactoring issue gone. Really in case if class contained URL or URLRequest property bundle was incorrect.

e.g. three classes declared in same module, and bundle is different:

```
class WithRequest {
    var request: URLRequest?
}

class WithURL {
    var url: URL?
}

class WithString {
    var string: String?
}

print(Bundle(for: WithRequest.self)) //Incorrect App Bundle
print(Bundle(for: WithURL.self)) //Incorrect App Bundle
print(Bundle(for: WithString.self)) //Correct bundle
```

Comment: This still sounds like a bug. Is the behavior the same in Xcode 9?